How to connect BI tool to database through Tailscale subnet
I am currently looking to connect our business intelligence platform to a database that can be accessed through a Tailnet Subnet Router. I am unsure as to the tactics to allow Tailscale to access/allow a series of public IP's to be whitelisted through the network. I have tried a couple of different methods with no luck.
I have set the IP's needed to be whitelisted as hosts, like so:
{
    "hosts": {
        "grow-1": "52.203.193.180",
        "grow-2": "52.0.63.147",
        "grow-3": "18.209.80.4",
        "grow-4": "13.42.173.220",
    },
}

This is the way my ACL's look like:
{
    "action": "accept",
    "src": [
        "group:engineering",
        "group:analysis",
        "host:grow-1",
        "host:grow-2",
        "host:grow-3",
        "host:grow-4",
    ],
    "dst": ["X.X.X.0/20:*"],
},

I can verify that the subnet router is working correctly by accessing the database from my local environment.
